# How to only display model field value with same data only once in Django templates?

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

```
class report(models.Model):
    Citizennumber = models.IntegerField()
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Patientfile = models.FileField(upload_to="Report")
    Description= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Hospitalname= models.CharField(max_length=50, default="blank")
    uploaddate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

How do I loop through this models in django templates so that if 'report.Hospitalname' has same value in multiple objects and I only want to print it once in templates?

Comment: Please do not store your report that way. Add a `ForeignKey` to a `Hospital` model.

Comment: Furthermore please show the current view and template.

Answer (score 1):

First you should order the queryset by `Hospitalname`.

```py
reports = Report.objects.order_by('Hospitalname')
```

Then you can use the template tag [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) to print the Hospitalname when it changes through iterations:

```
{% for report in reports %}
    {% ifchanged report.Hospitalname %}
        <h1>{{ report.Hospitalname }}</h1>
    {% endifchanged %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```